# Stuck in Wall after rectangle bounding box collision

Tags: xna, collision-detection

Using XNA's built in Intersects() on two Rectangles, I can detect a collision and set my velocity to zero. However, the object is stuck there and can't get out! How can I resolve this collision properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because once your object gets into the wall and you find the collision, you're simply stopping the object's movement by setting its velocity to zero, but the object is **still** within that wall.

To fix it, you have to **resolve** the collision by moving the object. You have two options here:

- Move the object back to its old position, by applying the opposite of the velocity to cancel the movement as soon as you detect a collision. **Pros:** extremely easy to implement. If it doesn't affect your game play go with this option. **Cons:** This will prevent the object from moving in any direction that would cause a collision (so you won't be able to slide along a wall for example).
- Find from where the object is and resolve the collision accordingly. For example, if the object came from the left and collided on the left side of the wall, you would simply move the object just to the left of the wall. By repeating this to all the sides of the rectangles, the object would be allowed to keep moving towards its desired velocity but would still avoid collisions.

---

**Implementation of second option**

Here I'll assume that the velocity represents the direction in which the object is going (basically that you are **not** changing the velocity between the object's position change and the collision check). I'll also assume that your origin is positioned at the top-left of the image (so when moving the object to resolve the collision I'll position the top-left corner).

Here is how I would do:

```
if (objRect.Intersects(wallRect)) // If there is a collision
{
    Vector2 newPos = obj.Position;

    if (obj.Velocity.X > 0) // object came from the left
        newPos.X = wallRect.Left - objRect.Width;
    else if (obj.Velocity.X < 0) // object came from the right
        newPos.X = wallRect.Right;
    if (obj.Velocity.Y > 0) // object came from the top
        newPos.Y = wallRect.Top - objRect.Height;
    else if (obj.Velocity.Y < 0) // object came from the bottom
        newPos.Y = wallRect.Bottom;

    obj.Position = newPos;
}
```

You could also use the old object's position to find where the object is from, but using the velocity is simpler in this case.

Comment: Okay, so basically it's stuck in the wall and the collision is continuing. How would I go about resolving this though?

Comment: Was editing it as you asked. Would you like some code samples to show how both options would be implemented?

Comment: I tried implementing the first one earlier by implementing a vector called a direction which is a normalized vector with left or right depending on key pressed, then I multiplied this by the velocity when collision was detected. This worked on the most part, but it only seems to work on one side of the rectangle (the right side?). For the second one, I would much appreciate a code sample as I've heard a lot about this but haven't seen any concrete implementations.

Comment: For the first one you would only need to do `object.Position -= object.Velocity` before you set your velocity to zero and it should do. For the second one, editing my answer to show how I usually implement it.

Comment: Your first option should be an example of what not to do. Any game with that type of collision detection, I would consider defective.

Comment: Well I guess it depends on the type of the game but yeah I always go for the second option.

Comment: @Jesse Emond - Thanks! The code seemed to work perfectly! I'm only a bit confused at how you stated that "you are not changing the velocity between the object's position change and the collision check". I changed the velocity on my KeyDown() events and then added it to the position. However, at the end of the method, I reset velocity to zero. Yet when I do this now, my character doesn't move at all. Of course, if I don't reset velocity, then it'll just keep moving regardless if I hold down the key or not.

Comment: Oh, that is perfectly fine. I didn't explain myself properly. What I meant is that it will only work if you use the same velocity that you used to move the object. Basically it just means that you should resolve collisions right after changing the object's position (because you use that same velocity to check where the object is from). You can forget that sentence it is not important since you're probably doing it this way anyway.

Comment: Is there a correct order of updates? Right now, when I go to a left wall, then press right, I somehow warp to the other side of that block. I've uploaded the relevant code in Update() here: http://pastebin.com/qf5WNtB1

Comment: I think the problem is that after I set the velocity to the end of the method, then press, say, right, then the collision passes and it thinks it came from the left since the velocity is greater than 0. Then it'll try to resolve it from the other side.

Comment: Why is this answer not accepted if you managed to implement the given method and it worked?

Comment: Ah ok.
Is the problem not that you change the velocity __just__ before the collision is resolved, and so it is resolved in the wrong direction. This will make the object enter even further the wall, and continue resolving the collision until it has exited.

Comment: This could in fact be your problem. You have to move the player first and THEN check for collisions with the velocity that you used. You should do it in this order: check for input, move player, resolve collisions.

Comment: @3nixios and @Jesse Edmond - This is in fact my problem! Thank you to both of you for your patience and help! Answer accepted :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in various ways.

One method is storing the previous position of the Rectangle every frame. So, when your rectangles Intersects, just set the object position to the older one that not collided. This method is not the best, because if the Rectangle velocity is high, you may see the reposition that you made via code.

Another method is testing the collision with a Raycast, so you can preview a collision before it ever happens.

Take a look at msdn for documentation for Raycast collision, and you'll be able to do that.