# Bounding box collision handling makes player glitch to the other side of the wall

Tags: collision-detection, python, pygame

The way I handle simple collision detection causes a really frequent and easy to reproduce glitch, which affects gameplay severely. Here's my code (Python 3.5):

```
 def move(self, _map):
    self.col = False
    for y in _map.actors:
        for actor in y:
            if actor[1]:
                if not (((self.y + self.h) < (actor[1].y - self.cam.y)) or (self.y > ((actor[1].y - self.cam.y) + actor[1].h)) or (self.x > ((actor[1].x - self.cam.x) + actor[1].w)) or ((self.x + self.w) < (actor[1].x - self.cam.x))):
                    print(self.col)
                    self.col = True
    if not self.col:
        if self.directions[0]:
            self.cam.y -= self.speed
        if self.directions[1]:
            self.cam.y += self.speed
        if self.directions[2]:
            self.cam.x -= self.speed
        if self.directions[3]:
            self.cam.x += self.speed
    else:
        if self.directions[0]:
            self.cam.y += self.speed
        if self.directions[1]:
            self.cam.y -= self.speed
        if self.directions[2]:
            self.cam.x += self.speed
        if self.directions[3]:
            self.cam.x -= self.speed
    if self.running:
        self.speed = system.RUNNING_PLAYER_SPEED
    else:
        self.speed = system.NORMAL_PLAYER_SPEED
    self.x = ((self.cam.w / 2) - (self.w / 2))
    self.y = ((self.cam.h / 2) - (self.h / 2))
```

As you can see, I'm detecting collision against walls and whatever (Any actor in the map) in the player's "move" method. The logic is pretty straightforward, [a basic bounding box collision test](http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/13/basic-collision-detection-in-2d-part-1/) (I consider the position of the player relative to the camera, since the player is always in the center (It's the camera that moves)).
If I just stop the player if there's a collision, the player gets stuck inside the wall, thus creating the necessity of "teleporting" the player to its former position, [as you can see in this other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/stuck-in-wall-after-rectangle-bounding-box-collision).
The problem with that solution is that it leads to this glitch, which I need to illustrate in order to make myself clear.

In this first example, I'm going up (pressing W) towards the wall.

[image]

The collision works fine just pressing W, it gets teleported in the opposite direction at each collision. The problem is when I start pressing S (Down) at the same time. The player goes **to the opposite** direction, glitching up towards the other side of the wall, since the collision test always returns true when the player is "inside" the wall, just like this:

[image]

This would severely compromise the gameplay, since players would be able to play outside the boundaries of the map in multiplayer. How can I avoid this using bounding box collision or other method?

Comment: Could you add a link to your github or bitbucket where I can download a complete working minimal example of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've finally realized how to solve the problem perfectly. I came to the conclusion that it's not a matter of detecting the collision in the present, but rather a matter of foreseeing the collision **in the future**. It's a matter of **time**! Either you record the positions of the player and then teleport him to his past in the event of a collision instead of moving him in the opposite direction in the present, or you check for a possible collision **in the future**. It works perfectly! The player can't get stuck inside the wall, or glitch through it, because the player **never gets there**! So that's the answer, future viewers: Accurate collision detection is all about **time**! (Not considering pixel-perfect detection, of course. That's not always necessary).

```
def move(self, _map):
    def check_collision(future_pos):
        for y in _map.actors:
            for actor in y:
                if actor[1]:
                    if not (((self.y + self.h) < (actor[1].y - future_pos[1])) or (self.y > ((actor[1].y - future_pos[1]) + actor[1].h)) or (self.x > ((actor[1].x - future_pos[0]) + actor[1].w)) or ((self.x + self.w) < (actor[1].x - future_pos[0]))):
                        return True
        return False
    if self.directions[0] and not check_collision((self.cam.x, self.cam.y - self.speed)):
        self.cam.y -= self.speed
    if self.directions[1] and not check_collision((self.cam.x, self.cam.y + self.speed)):
        self.cam.y += self.speed
    if self.directions[2] and not check_collision((self.cam.x - self.speed, self.cam.y)):
        self.cam.x -= self.speed
    if self.directions[3] and not check_collision((self.cam.x + self.speed, self.cam.y)):
        self.cam.x += self.speed
    if self.running:
        self.speed = system.RUNNING_PLAYER_SPEED
    else:
        self.speed = system.NORMAL_PLAYER_SPEED
    self.x = ((self.cam.w / 2) - (self.w / 2))
    self.y = ((self.cam.h / 2) - (self.h / 2))
```